# Add an external SOAP endpoint to SugarCRM (Integration)

Tags: web-services, soap, integration, sugarcrm

The main objective is to make a call **from SugarCRM** to external SOAP server.

Is it possible to add/configure an external SOAP WS endpoint (via WSDL) using SugarStudio or something similar without deep dive coding?

If **yes**, could you please help where to start? 
Else, what are the alternatives?

Many thanks

Comment: Pretty sure that you need code access to make calls to external SOAP services.

Comment: Thanks @Reisclef - Could you please share with us a tutorial, example or anything that can help to get started?